# On karatzas Definition of Kolmogorov-Feller diffusions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, definition

we find this definition on Karatzas [Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus pg 282]

[image]

[image]

But the definition of Kolmogorov Feller process does not seem to require that $Af$ be continuous in $x$ as is required in the definitions of Feller processes. for instance:

[image]

to be found on the site almost sure
(https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/feller-processes/)

Therefore my question is: Shouldn't a Kolmogorov-feller process be at least a Feller process? I mean shouldn't we require that $Af$ is continuous on $x \in E$.

Are there any other authors that use the same definition of Kolmogorov-Feller process?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question, but isn't the existence of $\cal A$  implies the continuity of $P$? The former is kind of derivative of the later.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but  the question is not about $P$ but about $Af$. we don't know if this is continuous if we only require $b,a$ to be measurable.